# Apply drupal theme

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-themes

I download Drupal theme(**goodnex**) from [here](http://bulkyfiles.com/new/goodnex.zip).
I applied it on my Drupal website, but it didn't work. CSS files are missing.

I'm using Drupal7 and kept my themes in `/sites/all/themes` folder.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What exactly is not working? Have you been able to enable the theme?

Comment: I'm getting a not found error on that link; hard to tell what's wrong with the theme without seeing it. Without being able to see any code, all I can say is: You're correct in where to put it for Drupal to find it on its own; is there any issue with permissions?

Answer (score 1):

Very often what causes it is that your webserver does not have access to your files folder so it other does not create the files or it can not read them.

1. Check your drupal files settings under /admin/config/media/file-system: 'Public file system path' and 'Temporary directory'.
2. Also check your actual folders permissions in the file system. Your files folder (/sites/default/files') is set to chmod 755 and works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible answer is that there are no CSS files.  If the theme is using SASS you might need to compile SASS first.

The link to the theme does not work, so I can't be sure...